# Ignore parameter in WHERE clause if it is set to null

Tags: mysql

I have a table which looks like this:

```
id c1 c2 c3 c4
1  2  3  4  5
2  2  4  4  5
```

I have a query which selects an object from table based on values in columns:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE c1= '2' and c2 = '3' and c3 = '4' and c4 = '5'
```

How would I ignore a part of `WHERE` condition if it is set to `null`?

For example if I'd query like:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE c1='2' and c2= null and c3 = '4' and c4 = '5'
```

I'd get both objects from table. Thank you.

Comment: SELECT * FROM table WHERE c1='2' and c3 = '4' and c4 = '5'

Comment: Are there any nulls in the columns c1, c2, ....

Comment: no, there are no nulls in table.

Comment: @AlexandrShaulskyi Do you want to return all rows just based on the condition if c2=null? You can easily do this by using `OR` like `(c1=2 AND c2=3 AND c3=4 AND c4=5) OR c2 = null`

Comment: If you don't care about the value of `c2` then don't put it into the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there are not any nulls in your columns you can use `COALESCE()` like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tablename 
WHERE c1 = COALESCE(@p1, c1) 
  AND c2 = COALESCE(@p2, c2)
  AND c3 = COALESCE(@p3, c3)
  AND c4 = COALESCE(@p4, c4)
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to completely ignore the null, you can check with in operator. you can use the COALESCE function.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE COALESCE(c1, '2') = '2' and COALESCE(c2,'3')='3' and COALESCE(c3, '4') = '4' and COALESCE(c4, '5') = '5'
```

This will match the c1 column for value 2 and nulls. in effect ignore any nulls.

However if you just want c2 to be ignored just use the coalesce on c2 alone